# What are the small red dots in the Visual studio scrollbar?

Tags: visual-studio-2019, editor

In Visual Studio 2019, using the Enhanced Scroll Bar, red square dots in the scroll bar's right-most column highlights where there are errors in the code. However, I have other red dots, smaller (half width, half height, approximately) in the left-most column of the scroll bar, or possibly at the very right end side of the editor window (?). [image: Small red dots together with orange, purple, red, blue and grey stuff]
What do they represent?